# Google Chrome extension - Restart eventlisteners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First of all, I am a newbie in chrome extension development.  I am developing a chrome extension to collect user inputs from a form on a specific webpage.

In my manifest.json, I have added javascripts to be used for this purpose inside "content_scripts" and they are invoked when the matched URL loads. In my javsacript, I have added eventlisteners for triggering functions when a button is clicked.

The problem I am facing is that, evenlisteners work fine and the required functions get executed when the button is clicked for first time.

But when the button is clicked for second time, it does not trigger the listener.

Can anyone please recommend me a way to overcome this issue?

Content script part of my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["*://domain/pathtofile*"],
"all_frames": true,
"js": ["myscript.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
}
]
```

And in "myscript.js", I use this:

```
document.getElementById("elementid").addEventListener("click", functiontocall);
```

Thank you

Sujith

------ Edit ------

Extension I am developing is for a specific client and this is an unlisted extension in chrome store. So I am not able to provide the URL due to NDA with client.

The URL (example: "http://www.domain.com/urlpath/form.php") has a DIV inside it, which contains an HTML form.  So when this URL is loaded, it matches with the manifest and loads a javascript "myscript.js".  In "myscript.js", I have written a code:

```
document.getElementById("formbuttonelement").addEventListener("click", getFormData);
```

The function "getFormData()" just contains basic javascripts to take values from each form element and prepare a query string and send to another PHP script ("collectForm.php") using AJAX.

After the form button is clicked, the DIV element will close.  In the web page, there is a button to open this DIV (HTML form) again, and user can input data in form and click "formbuttonelement" again to submit form.

So, my problem is that, when I open the URL "http://www.domain.com/urlpath/form.php" for the first time, everything works as expected, including the addEventListener part and I can get the form data in "collectForm.php".  And, as mentioned earlier, the DIV element will close.

But when the DIV is opened again (which does not load the URL again), addEventListener is not working.  I presume that it is because the URL is not reloading, thereby not invoking "myscript.js" again.

I am looking for an option to restart event listener even if the web page is not reloaded.

I hope I have explained the situation.

Thanks & Regards
Sujith

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your quick response. I have tried to explain the situation in detail by editing my question.

Comment: Ah, so the element is recreated. I think the simplest solution would be to attach a click listener to the closest parent element that is guaranteed to persist e.g. `document`. In the event callback you'll simply check whether the click is within the required element `if (e.target.closest('#formbuttonelement')) { console.log('Huzza!!!11'); }`